# Which presentation remote controls are OS X compatible with Powerpoint?

Tags: ms-office, hardware-recommendation, remote-control

I'm looking for a remote control to use for controlling a Powerpoint presentation, and want it to be compatible and reliable w/ OS X.  Any recommendations on one that functions well with Powerpoint?

Comment: Let's see what people think of this. Hardware shopping questions are explicitly off-topic, but if you are OK having this reflect an answer that explains how to know which are compatible or even pick some that function well in experience - that should be OK to keep open.

Comment: I wasn't too sure if this would be off-topic.  I should probably brush up on my Meta info :)  -- the compatibility approach was of interest though. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Logitech's R800 remote works. They aren't officially supported, but they allow you to flick back and forward between slides.